# Como se pueden escribir datos de un formulario en php en html

Tags: php, html, post, get

Estoy creando un formulario en php para carga de datos en una url privada, o sea a la cual sólo tiene acceso el administrador del sitio y necesito escribir esos datos en una página html pública con un include o con algún otro método y que queden publicados hasta que se vuelva a modificar el formulario, tal vez por una semana.

Estos datos los recojo con el método post en otro php de la siguiente manera para que el usuario pueda ver como queda y de ahi postearlo con un include en el html.

```
$fecha1 = $_POST['fecha1'];
echo "<h1 class='fecha'>$fecha1</h1>"  ;
echo "<div class='divline'></div>";
$ds1 = $_POST['ds1'];
echo nl2br("<p class='descrip'>$ds1</p>");
$ralink1 = $_POST['ralink1'];
echo "<a href='$ralink1'target='_blank' class='ralink'>$ralink1</a>";
echo "<div class='divline'></div>";
```

Hay algún método para escribir estos datos sin tener almacenarlos en la base de datos_?

He estado leyendo en foros y  algunos sugieren hacerlo con document.write() en js pero no sé si eso me sirve.

Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que generas puedes almacenarlo en un string usando las funciones de *output buffering* ([control de salida](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.outcontrol.php)) y almacenando en un archivo fijo en el sistema de archivos:

```
ob_start(); // inicio captura de datos
$fecha1 = $_POST['fecha1'];
echo "<h1 class='fecha'>$fecha1</h1>"  ;
echo "<div class='divline'></div>";
$ds1 = $_POST['ds1'];
echo nl2br("<p class='descrip'>$ds1</p>");
$ralink1 = $_POST['ralink1'];
echo "<a href='$ralink1'target='_blank' class='ralink'>$ralink1</a>";
echo "<div class='divline'></div>";
$content=ob_get_clean(); // captura de los datos generados en una variable
file_put_contents('/ruta/a/carpeta/publica/post.html',$content); //guardar en archivo
```

Luego puedes incluir dicho archivo en alguna otra pagina PHP:

```
<?php include('/ruta/a/carpeta/publica/post.html') ?>
```

O mostrarla directamente de usando la ruta publica:

```
https://mi.sitio/carpeta/publica/post.html
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte Igor!
Voy a probarlo y luego te cuento como me ha ido!
Saludos!

Comment: Igor, he probado lo que me recomendaste y funciona en Xampp.
Pero al implementarlo en el servidor recibo el siguiente error.

Warning: file_put_contents(/post.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/u884635543/domains/tonydeepdisco.com/public_html/postedgigs.php on line 65

Comment: Warning: include(/post.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u884635543/domains/tonydeepdisco.com/public_html/index.php on line 280

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/post.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in /home/u884635543/domains/tonydeepdisco.com/public_html/index.php on line 280

Comment: Ahora sí!
Es que no había puesto la ruta completa en el include!
Gracias Igor!

Comment: Que buena noticia! si pudiste solicionarlo con esto marca la respuesta como correcta, si alguna duda queda no dudes en preguntar, saludos